# probability for ball replacement

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Three boxes of the same appearance have the following proportion of balls
 Box I : 2 black 1 white
 Box II : 1 black 2 white and
 Box III : 2 black 2 white
One of the box is selected at random and one ball is drawn. It turns out to be white. 
What is the probability of drawing white ball again, if the first one drawn is not
replaced?

Comment: I am using Bayes theorem

Comment: three cases will arise depending upon from where white ball is taken out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're interested in the probability,

$$\mathbb{P}(2nd \;W | 1st \; W) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(1st \; W, 2nd \; W)}{\mathbb{P}(1st \; W)} $$

To find the denominator, condition on the which boxes where chosen,

\begin{array} \mathbb{P}(1st \; W) &=& \mathbb{P}(1st \; W | Box \; 1)\mathbb{P}(Box \; 1) + \mathbb{P}(1st \; W | Box \; 2)\mathbb{P}(Box \; 2)+\mathbb{P}(1st \; W | Box \; 3)\mathbb{P}(Box \; 3) \\
&=& \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{4}\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}

To find the numerator, do same thing, except we're conditioning the event, $1st \; White$ AND $2nd \; White$, on the boxes chosen,

\begin{array} \mathbb{P}(1st \; W, 2nd \; W) &=& \mathbb{P}(1st \; W, 2nd \; W | Box \; 1)\mathbb{P}(Box \; 1) + \mathbb{P}(1st \; W, 2nd \; W | Box \; 2)\mathbb{P}(Box \; 2)+\mathbb{P}(1st \; W, 2nd \; W | Box \; 3)\mathbb{P}(Box \; 3) \\
&=& 0 + \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{4}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\end{array}